Probability that a specific card appears before turning up exactly two aces when turning cards from a random deck?
I'm just adopting this new idea of "symmetry" in probability. To solve the question in the title. My reasoning is: we have five places for a specific card(out of $48$ different cards from $4$ aces) relative to aces:
$$-A_{1}-A_{2}-A_{3}-A_{4}-$$
Assuming that 52 cards are randomly shuffled, that card can be equally likely in these 5 regions. So it's $\frac{2}{5}$ probable that a card appears before turning up exactly two aces. But this is wrong when applying this idea to this problem:

Cards from an ordinary deck are turned face up one at a time. Compute
the expected number of cards that need to be turned face up in order
to obtain
(a) 2 aces;

Let us denote $X$ is the number of cards before first two aces.  $X = X_1 + X_2 +... +X_{48}$ where $X_{i} = 1$ if card $i$ appears before turning up exactly two aces, $0$ otherwise. It should be clear that $E(X) = 48 * \frac{2}{5} = 19.2$ which is wrong. The correct answer is $21.2$. Where am I going wrong?

You're forgetting to count the two aces.

Right? XD. Always these bits

X is counting the number of cards being turned up, including the two aces in question. So the correct expression for $X$ should be:
$$X = 2 + X_1 + X_2 +... X_{48}$$
